# Select from 2 tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a SQL query, for multiple condition select from 2 tables.

```
table1
order_row | timestamp |
-----------------------
0001      |2016-11-04 |
0002      |2016-11-04 |
0003      |2016-11-04 |
0004      |2016-11-03 |
0006      |2016-11-03 |

table2
order_row | timestamp |
-----------------------
0001      |2016-11-05 |
0002      |2016-11-04 |
0003      |2016-11-04 |
0004      |2016-11-04 |
0005      |2016-11-04 |
0006      |2016-11-02 |
```

I want to get all rows so that I get all `order_row` rows from `table2` which are not present in `table1` and `order_row` rows from `table2` whose timestamp is newer in `table2` than `table1`. And checks only rows from `table 2` where `timestamp` is newer than 2016-11-03.
Result must be:

```
order_row | 
----------
0001      | because timestamp is newer in table2
0004      | because timestamp is newer in table2
0005      | because it's not present in table1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 
   ON t2.order_row = t1.order_row 
WHERE t1.order_row IS NULL OR t2.`timestamp` > t1.`timestamp`
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/604f50/2)

**Edit:** If you want only records from `table2` newer than `'2016-11-03'` to be considered, then simply add:

```
t2.`timestamp` > '2016-11-03' AND ( ... other conditions here ...)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. i have an additional question. how i add condition where query checks rows from table 2 where timestamp is newer than 2016-11-03 for example.

Comment: @Kalle You can add the predicate `t2.timestamp > '2016-11-03'` and combine it with `t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp` in case you want newer records *and* records past the specific date.

Comment: @Kalle Glad I was able to help  Please mark this or any other answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.